# Sound crackles and echos to the point of being unusable

Tags: debian, audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I recently got a new desktop, installed debian 64 bit, and found out that the sound doesn't work at all. I'm not entirely sure what information I should give to help identify the problem but I'll do my best...

The motherboard provides the sound, an Asus Z97 A, which has a Realtek ALC892 chip for sound.

I tried editting /etc/pulse/default.pa to add tsched=0. I also tried adding default-sampling-rate = 48000 to /etc/pulse/daemon.pa. And I also tried running as admin and adding myself to the audio group. None of that helped.

I also tried upgrading my kernel using wheezy backports from 3.2 to 3.14. It changed what weird sound I heard instead of the correct sound, but didn't actually help.

I also tried adding the line `snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0` to /etc/modules and /etc/modprobe.d/fix-audio.pref (alternately, not both together).

Right now I'm running kernel version 3.12, because my video card driver doesn't support 3.14, and 3.2 spat out errors about the hda-codec on bootup. 3.12 got rid of the errors, but sound still doesn't play properly.

In BIOS I changed the frontport audio from hd audio to AC97. This made it so that I can actually hear the sound I'm playing, not just garbled junk, but it still crackles and echos. The sound is much better in chrome than in the default player for .mp3 files, which seems to simply be called movie player.

Comment: I have the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a program that I was using, to fix it I downloaded a new sound driver. There are a lot of drivers, I use [ASIO4ALL v2](http://www.asio4all.com/) I like it but it is for a program and the program itself launches it. it isn't default, so make sure you set it up like you want it.

sorry if this doesn't help

Comment: I linked the driver, but seeing as this as a Linux Forum, and that's a Windows Driver, how does this help, i.e do you know of a Linux version?

Comment: I do not. I have only done this for windows, but I thought it might help. if you google linux sound drivers maybe you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem on Debian Wheezy, when I upgraded to Jessie the issue went away.